# Error using rcorr() on matrix with NA values

Tags: r, correlation, pearson-correlation

I am using a matrix (n=1000) with 150 variables of interest. I would like correlate an exposure to each of the 150 variables, ideally using a correlation table with p-values. I am trying to use `rcorr()` on my matrix. I'm able to create this table using sample data (like `mtcars`) but am unable to create the table using my data due to this error:

> Error in rcorr("mydata") : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion

Seems like this is due to my matrix having NA in place of missing data. Here's a screenshot of my printed matrix:

[image]

How can I call the `rcorr()` function on my data while ignoring the NA values?

Comment: Hello goose144, you would help us a lot if you could add a sample of your data. Others have to replicate the phenomenon on their systems in order to help you. You can do that e.g. using `dput(head(mydata))`.

Comment: Thanks Jan! unfortunately I don't have the permission to, due to patient privacy/research restrictions. Are there any descriptive questions I can answer? Or is there a way for me to upload something similar to my data without actually uploading the data?

Comment: your data looks like character . Use `str(yourdata)` to see the class of the variables.

Comment: ... and I'm assuming you are using `?Hmisc::rcorr`; the help page describes how missing are autoimatcally deleted pairwise

Comment: That's correct -- I'm using Hmisc. What is the relevance of pairwise deletions for missing data? Does that suggest that the error is not related to the presence of "NA" in my matrix? Thanks

Comment: The pairwise deletion automatically deals with the missing. The issue is that your data are not numeric and so the correlations cannot be calculated

Comment: Aha. Previously I had the data as a dataframe; I converted it to a matrix because I had a different error with rcorr(). With the dataframe, the data are numeric. When I call rcorr() on the dataframe, the error is:"Error in storage.mode(x) <- "double" : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"

Comment: quick general comment: It is good practice to keep inspecting your data as you carry out calculations and data manipulations to make sure that it is producing the results you expect. I liberally use `str` to do this. Use `str(yourdataframe)` to check the class of the variables straight after data import -- are the variables the expected class? If not, why not? Also if you have created a matrix from a dataframe which contained a mix of numeric and character/factor variables all variables will be coerced to character (as a matrix can only hold one type of variable)

Comment: Ok, good advice thank you. After calling str(dataframe), I see that I have int, num, and factor as my variable classes. Factor for dates, int and num for numerical values. I'm not sure why some numbers are "int" and some are "num". Are you familiar with the "list cannot be coerced to type 'double'" error?

Comment: its okay that some variables are `int` -- they are still numeric (as far as calculating correlation matters). Yes I have seen that error; what code did it some from? edit: ah  sorry, you get it from `rcorr` -- help page says the input has to be a numeric matrix. So take care when changing your dataframe to matrix.

Comment: ... something like this may work; `mat_dat = as.matrix(yourdataframe[sapply(yourdataframe, is.numeric)]); rcorr(mat_dat)`